# Filter out directories using Makefile list

Tags: bash, makefile, build

I'm trying to make this release rule for my makefile
It's job is to copy the directories in the folder, except for a few (like the destination etc)
I have looked at the makefile **filter** function but it seems like it's not working inside of the bash loop?
Is there an easy way to filter out the items in the list in bash?

```
SOURCE_DIR=builds/$(NAME)_$(VERSION)

#List of items to ignore
IGNORE=builds cfg compiled

release:
if [ -d "cfg" ]; then \
    cp -r cfg $(SOURCE_DIR)/cfg; \
fi;
for folder in *; do \
    if [ -d "$$folder" ]; then \
            if [[ $(IGNORE) != $$folder ]]; then \
                cp -r $$folder $(SOURCE_DIR)/addons/; \
            fi; \
    fi; \
done;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [filter-out function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) is a Make function, so if you want to use it, you must use it before you pass the command to the shell.

You can use it outside the rule:

```
THINGS := $(wildcard *)
IGNORE = builds cfg compiled
THINGS := $(filter-out $(IGNORE), $(THINGS))

release:
    @for folder in $(THINGS); do \
      if [ -d $$folder ]; then \
        echo $$folder; \
      fi; \
     done
```

or inside the rule:

```
THINGS := $(wildcard *)
IGNORE = builds cfg compiled

release:
    @for folder in $(filter-out $(IGNORE), $(THINGS)); do \
      if [ -d $$folder ]; then \
        echo $$folder; \
      fi; \
     done
```

Or you could stick with `for folder in *...` and filter the list in bash:

```
IGNORE = builds cfg compiled

release:
    @for folder in *; do \
      if [ -d $$folder ]; then \
        [[ "$(IGNORE)" =~ $$folder ]] || echo $$folder; \
      fi; \
     done
```